# Parse, how to do a lookup by PFRelation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm attempting to find all of the conversations between friends on my application, and my friends are stored in a `PFRelation`.

I'm looking for something similar to the

```
PFObject#whereKey(key: String, containedIn: [AnyObject])
```

method that will accept a PFRelation.

Basically, what I need this query to do is the following:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "foo")
query.whereAtleastOneKey(keys: [String], containedIn: PFRelation)
```

Because my keys are namely "user_a" and "user_b" so I need to check to see if user_a or user_b contains the id stored in the PFRelation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the query from the relation and a compound query. The appropriate methods are [`whereKey:matchesQuery:`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)whereKey:matchesQuery:) and [`orQueryWithSubqueries:`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(cm)orQueryWithSubqueries:).

Comment: I still fail to see how executing another query is going to help in the situation, considering my original problem is that I need to find all of the results where key A OR key B is equal to a value.

Comment: You don't execute 2, you put them together and send as a single request

Comment: I'm not able to figure this out, could you provide an example where `key a or key b is = to string`? Or will i have to run two queries?